# Directory creating in wrong home

Tags: linux, bash, directory, root, deb

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
configdir="${XDG_CACHE_HOME:-$HOME/.config}/example"
datadir="${XDG_DATA_HOME:-$HOME/.local/share}/example"
mkdir -m 666 "$configdir"
mkdir -m 666 "$datadir"
```

This postinst script in deb package is creating directories in `/root`, instead of creating directories inside `/home/usrname`. What Am I doing wrong?

Comment: `XDG_CACHE_HOME` already has a value `/root`

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/23463/how-to-create-debian-package-to-install-files-to-home-user/23464

Comment: If you're using `sudo` use `sudo -E` to keep _your_ environment variables.